# How can I check in a launch file if a roscore is already running?

Tags: ros, roslaunch, multiple, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!

I am implementing a system that has a GUI for visualization. The core system starts with a roslaunch file and the GUI with another one. Ideally the GUI should open and close when wanted.

The problem I'm facing is the following: If I run roslaunch for GUI in console A and then roslaunch for my core application in console B and close the GUI, the roslaunch in console A does not terminate (probably because roscore and rosout are attached to it and other nodes from console B need them).

So is there any way to modify GUI roslaunch to not start a roscore, or even initialize the nodes only if roscore is already active?

Thnx in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/111131/how-can-i-check-in-a-launch-file-if-a-roscore-is-already-running?/) by [etsardou](https://answers.ros.org/users/10001/etsardou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-12-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure to understand your problem, but could't you run the roscore in a terminal A,  the GUI in a terminal B and your core application in a terminal C? Moreover (I don't know if this can be useful) you could set the property `required="true"` for the node that launches the GUI, so that when the GUI is killed, all other nodes started from the same launch file should die.

EDIT:

To make a launch file wait for a roscore you should put `--wait` in the command line, as described [here](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Commandline%20Tools#Launch_syntax)

---

Originally posted by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) with karma: 808 on 2013-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [etsardou](https://answers.ros.org/users/10001/etsardou/) on 2013-12-16**:
Of course I can run GUI after core was created, but in general the whole system is distributed. So GUI can be launched in another PC without knowing if a core exists in the server. Anyway, the real question is about telling a launcher to not begin if a roscore is not already running.

**Comment by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) on 2013-12-16**:
See the edit of my answer.